# Not able to connect Apache drill/dremio with Nifi 1.8.0

Tags: apache-nifi

I am not able to connect with apache drill with nifi-1.8.0 but able to connect with nifi-1.7.1.

I am using ExecuteSql processor to connect with apache drill using jdbc connection string.
In the case of nifi-1.8.0 poolableExcecption is coming.

```
 Unable to execute SQL select query SELECT * from test.wellRecords due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (null). No FlowFile to route to failure: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (null)
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (null)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:308)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPService.getConnection(DBCPService.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:84)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.AbstractExecuteSQL.onTrigger(AbstractExecuteSQL.java:195)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1165)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:203)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (null)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2385)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2110)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:305)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: null
    at oadd.org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.unsupported(Helper.java:53)
    at oadd.org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.isValid(AvaticaConnection.java:325)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.isValid(DrillConnectionImpl.java:657)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:874)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:270)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:389)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2398)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2381)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

I want to connect with nifi-1.8.0 processor because all the nifi configuration is written in this current nifi version.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet on the question, so here are some thoughts that will hopefully be of help.

- Are you using the same jdbc driver as in nifi-1.7?
- Nifi has dropped commons-dbcp-1.4 in favour of commons-dbcp2-2.5 in version 1.8.
  [Link to pom.xml](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/rel/nifi-1.8.0/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-services/nifi-dbcp-service-bundle/nifi-dbcp-service/pom.xml)

From reading the stacktrace there is a problem validating the connection to the database server. [Maybe others have similar issues?](https://community.dremio.com/t/hikaricp-dremio-jdbc-feature-not-supported-exception/1797) Are you setting a validation query?

Comment: I have a solution for my above connection and exception. In DBCP Connection Pool configuration we need to use the option ValidateQuery.
 In the ValidateQuery Option, we need to pass :- "ValidateQuery = Select 1"